# Can ideas be perfectly illustrated using non-mathematical language?

Tags: philosophy-of-language, wittgenstein

Reading through many philosophy forums it seems like many ideas get bogged down in the definitions of ideas which seem to go down an endless spiral of caveats and contradictions depending on who interprets it.

The easiest descriptions of items which (I interpret) to get an idea across in the simplest ways are mathematical, such as one or two or even if they exist.

Outside of these mathematical descriptions, can anything truly be described in a way which perfectly gets an idea across from your perspective to another person of a different perspective?

Comment: Quite unclear... most (99,999% ?) of book dealing with philosophy, art, society, culture, politics, etc etc "describe" ideas without mathematical formulas.

Answer (score 1):

Yes they can, using diagrams.

There are the similar Spider Diagram and Cluster Diagram. Here is a generic Spider Diagram example from [The Organic Mind](https://www.the-organic-mind.com/spider-diagrams.html)

[image]

There are also Mind Maps, such as this example from [*The Guardian*](https://www.theguardian.com/careers/mind-mapping-tony-buzzan)

[image]

Comment: Can you provide an example? I've seen a few people making this claim, but I haven't seen a good demonstration ever. (I find these diagrams good as a tool for having my own thoughts, under certain circumstances, but not as a tool for communication.)

Comment: Which particular **idea** do you have in mind? An idea isn't always perfectly representable.

Comment: As you find these diagrams useful as a tool for your own thoughts, they should be a good way for you to communicate your qualia, which are personal and subjective.

Comment: I meant "the concept of qualia". Though, I have _tried_ and _failed_ to use these diagrams to communicate specific qualia, in the past. I might just be doing it wrong: if you can successfully demonstrate the communication of a concept via a spider diagram, I'd be much obliged. (If you choose to demonstrate, please pick something that you think is a good demonstration of the approach.)

Comment: First, present your mathematical approach. It's your call, not mine.

Comment: My answer was simple: by using a diagram. I don't get how you would use math to communicate an ***idea*** at all, but if you can, most people will understand a diagram far more easily.

Comment: I think the question was referring to mathematical descriptions of mathematical concepts, not asserting that all concepts admit a mathematical description.